# asp.net mvc dynamic data article

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic-data

Can someone point me to great startup article over the mixture of ASP.NET MVC and Dynamic Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Scott Hanselman article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) has a pretty good explanation.